# After pseudo element not showing as it should

Tags: html, css

So im trying to underline the menu links on hover with a pseudo element but its not working the way it should. On hover over the menu links the after element appears but through all the width of the col div instead of just under the link. Code below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="cover">      
       <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="logo"><span>CS</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <nav id="menu" class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="menu-item">
                                <a class="active" href="#">Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-item">
                                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-item">
                                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-item">
                                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-item">
                                <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-skype"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="social-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        html, body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: "Myriad Pro", serif;
    }


    .slicknav_menu {
        display:none;
    }
    .container-fluid {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .menu {
        margin-top: 45px;
    }
    .cover {
         background-image: url("../img/cover.png");
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: auto;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .menu > ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline;

    }
    .menu >ul > li {
        display: inline-block;


    }
    .menu-item {
        margin-right: 47px;
    }
    nav ul .menu-item a:after{
        position: absolute;
      content: '';
      height: 2px;
      bottom: -15px;
      /*margin: 0 auto;*/
        left: 0;
      right: 0;
        width: 0%;
      -o-transition:.5s;
      -ms-transition:.5s;
      -moz-transition:.5s;
      -webkit-transition:.5s;
      transition:.5s;
    }
    nav ul .menu-item a:hover:after {
        width: 100%;
      background: #e50606;
    }
    /*nav ul li a:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      height: 2px;
      bottom: -15px;
      margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
      right: 0;
        width: 0%;
      -o-transition:.5s;
      -ms-transition:.5s;
      -moz-transition:.5s;
      -webkit-transition:.5s;
      transition:.5s;
    }
    nav ul li a:hover:after {
      width: 100%;
      background: #e50606;
    }*/
    .menu > ul > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .menu ul li a:hover {
        color: #11749E;
    }
    .logo {
        position: relative;
        margin: 22px 0 0 50px;
        width: 67px;
        height: 67px;
        background-color: #11749e;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 8px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 8px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow: 12px 8px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }
    .logo span {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #fff;

    }
    .social-icon {
        margin-right: 30px;
    }



    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
        /* #menu is the original menu */
         #menu {
            display:none;
        }

         .slicknav_menu {
            display:block;
        }
    }
```

This css worked on another website, cannot find why its not working now.

Comment: There is no CSS here...?

Comment: Sorry was editing the post

Comment: I put your code in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/53g2moqn/), but nothing happens on hover. Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this what you wanted, but I edited your `nav` section code a bit. make the `:hover` to be on the `li` or `.menu-item` instead of on the `a` tag and add a `position: relative` on the `li`

```css
.menu > ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

.menu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item {
  margin-right: 47px;
}

nav ul .menu-item:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

nav ul li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0%;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu" class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a class="active" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Its working just as i wanted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: hope it helps! please accept this answer as well :) @MauroSirotich